# XML documentation comment for method with list as a parameter

Tags: c#, c++, managed-c++, sandcastle, xml-documentation

I am writing a XML documentation for a managed C++ method accepting a List as a parameter using Sandcastle documentation builder.

I am seeing an error [Missing  documentation for "[M: namespace.Import(System.Collections.Generic.List{System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2})]" in the HTML output. I see the similar error where such method is referred using .

Here is the sample code -

```
/// <summary>
/// Stores the certificates securely.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// Consumers can securely store their X.509 digital certificates using <see cref="Import"/> method.
/// </remarks>
public ref CertificateVault {

    /// <summary>
    /// Imports the certificates into the vault.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Some method remarks.
    /// </remarks>
    /// <param name="certs">Certificates to import</param>
    void Import(List<X509Certificate^>^ certs);
}
```

I have tried following combinations but none of them worked.

```
/// <see cref="Import(List{T})" />
/// <see cref="Import(List&lt;X509Certificate2>)" />
/// <see cref="Import(List&lt;X509Certificate2^>)" />
/// <see cref="Import(List&lt;X509Certificate2^>^)" />
/// <see cref="Import(System.Collections.Generic.List`1{System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2})" />
/// <see cref="Import(List&lt;X509Certificate2&gt;)" />
/// <see cref="Import(List&lt;X509Certificate2^&gt;)" />
/// <see cref="Import(List&lt;X509Certificate2^&gt^;)" />
/// <see cref="Import(List`{X509Certificate2}`)"/>
/// <see cref="Import(List&lt;X509Certificate2^&gt;)" />
/// <see cref="Import(List&lt;X509Certificate2^&gt^;)" />
/// <see cref="Import(List`{X509Certificate2}`)"/>
```

What am I missing here?